# Get GitHub gist file URL with syntax coloring?

Tags: github

I just pasted this multi-file gist:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/57e871d6779a0a38354f

For some reason, GitHub decides to display both 20K+ line- files in full, making the master page a bit unresponsive. So I thought I'd work with links to individual files.

GitHub for the main file links provides this:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/57e871d6779a0a38354f#file-test-tex

... which is basically an anchor into the exact same address as the first above.

And then, a raw link is provided:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/57e871d6779a0a38354f/raw/560a455b063f177e7bba7a4a32320a66f56b3388/testlog.diff

... which, being plain text, obviously contains no syntax coloring.

There is also this under the link titled "view the full file" (where it appears):

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/57e871d6779a0a38354f/raw/testlog.diff

... but it again serves a plain text file, with no syntax coloring.

Can I somehow obtain a link to a single file that will be served using GitHub's usual syntax coloring display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe Github offers the ability to view a single highlighted file that is part of a multi-file gist, unfortunately.

You could:

A) Re-paste that file into it's own separate gist.

B) Use another service to highlight code for you such as [Rouge](http://rouge.jneen.net). It's an open source project that does syntax highlighting and allows you to [save](http://rouge.jneen.net/pastes/PM1) the data you highlighted for viewing or sharing.

Sorry it's not exactly what you wanted, but perhaps one of these might work for you.